# XML Validates and XSLT fine but it does not return the result I wished

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, xsd

I am currently doing XML and XSLT and I have a question

I have done everything and validates fine but does not give me the right answer. One solution that worked fine was using CDATA but I want to use the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/xhtml.

here is my relevant code

XML Schema

```
        <xs:element name="bb">
            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                            minOccurs="0"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                            processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:sequence>          
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="xsi:bb">
    <div style="font-family:calibri;font-size:16">
        <span style="color:#000"> 
            Babo is: 
        </span> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

XML

```
<bb>
    <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
        hoby
    </li> 

    <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
        the best
    </li> 
</bb>
```

According to my theory it should return (when I convert XML to HTML)

hoby

the best

but it is just returning hoby the best.

Why?

Comment: Your XML is not valid. No opening `<p>` and no closing `</li>`. Also, in your XSLT, what do you expect `<xsl:template match="xsi:description">` to match in your input XML?

Comment: sorry wrong example have fixed it. even if XMl is valid still returns an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need apply templates on li elements. xsl:value-of run for a subtree will read and concatenate all text nodes. AFAIR (may be wrong - you may want to double check this) disable output escaping is used for the content of the text node and not for elements text nodes belong too. The reason is that the li elements (in your case) are seperate elements in the tree and are internally treated as such and not as elements. If you want just to copy li elements as is you can just use something like this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="xhtml:li" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

(or if you want to copy all elements:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*" />
```

)

Answer (score 0):

**Learn about the difference between**:

[**`<xsl:value-of>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#value-of)

**and**

**[`<xsl:copy-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#copy-of)**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what namespace the prefix "xsi" is bound to, but the conventional binding for this prefix is the XML schema instance namespace, which is unlikely to contain an element called xsi:bb. Probably for this reason, your template rule is not matching anything, and you just get the output from the default template for text nodes.